# Kotlin Scope Functions: Smart Cast Error when declaring two variables with the same name in two different scope functions

Tags: kotlin, scope

I was working on a LeetCode problem and started writing the following code:

```kotlin
class Solution {
    fun addTwoNumbers(l1: ListNode?, l2: ListNode?): ListNode? {
        val stack1 = ArrayDeque<Int>().apply {
            var tmp = l1
            while (tmp != null) {
                this.addLast(tmp.`val`)
                tmp = tmp.next
            }
        }
        val stack2 = ArrayDeque<Int>().apply {
            var tmp = l2
            while (tmp != null) {
                this.addLast(tmp.`val`)
                tmp = tmp.next
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

Compiling this results in the following error:

> Kotlin: Smart cast to 'ListNode' is impossible, because 'tmp' is a local variable that is captured by a changing closure

What exactly is the issue here? I am not able to reference `tmp` outside of the `apply` blocks, yet it still has some effect on my code. I don't get the error if the variables have different names, e.g. `tmp1` and `tmp2`.

Comment: This is a known problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19446/False-positive-Smart-cast-to-Foo-is-impossible-due-to-same-variable-names-in-different-closures Kotlin team says this is not a bug, but at least to me it doesn't look right.

Comment: Thank you for linking the issue. This doesn't seem intuitive to me either.